# Associating a Realm Object with a UITabBarController in iOS 9 with RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm, ios9

Below is a screenshot of the storyboard for my project:

[image: Realm UITabBarController Project]

As you can see, I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.  When the user adds an item to the `UITableView` a new Realm `Object` model which I have named `Project` is created (I'm using RealmSwift) and they are taken to the first item in the `UITabBarController`.  I'm wondering if it is possible to associate the `UITabBarController` and all of its child view controllers with the `Project` that is created.

Here is the code that creates the `Object` (which is working fine):

```
    func add(withName projectName: String) {
        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        dispatch_async(queue) {
            autoreleasepool {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let newProject = Project(value: ["name": projectName, "date": NSDate()])
                realm.write({ () -> Void in
                    realm.add(newProject)
                })
            }
        }
    }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        selectedProject = array[indexPath.row]
        print(selectedProject)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTab", sender: self)
    }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showTab" {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! TabBarViewController
                dvc.project = selectedProject

        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm passing the new `Project` to the `UITabBarController`.

Here is my code in the `UITabBarController`:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MasterTabViewController: UITabBarController {

    var project: Project?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavigationBar()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    }

    // MARK: - UI Styling
    private extension MasterTabViewController {
        func configureNavigationBar() {
            navigationItem.title = project?.name
        }

    }
```

This sets the title of all `UIViewController`s that descend from the `UITabBarController`.

Is there a way for me to make that `Project` object available to all view controllers that descend from the `UITabBarController`?  I haven't been able to find too much information on this.  One suggestion that I found was to store the `Object` in `NSUserDefaults` but it seems to me that there must be a better way.

EDIT:  I forgot to add that I can think of a way to do this with Core Data using `NSManagedObjectContext`, but I'm having some trouble seeing the equivalent in Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track! When a view controller is a child of a `UITabBarController`, you can access the tab bar controller from inside the child view controller with the `self.tabBarController` property.

Since you know these view controllers are children of a subclass of `UITabBarController` that also provides `Project` as a property, it should be a matter of simply calling that tab bar controller property, typecasting the resulting view controller to your tab bar controller subclass, and then calling the `project` property on it.

So, in any of your child controllers:

```
let project = (self.tabBarController as MasterTabViewController).project?
```

You could easily optimize this further by making `project` a read-only property of your child controller classes that calls this line of code automatically. Good luck!

Comment: That is the approach that I started to take this morning and I almost have it working how I want it to.  Your explanation helped clarify things.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to hear that! If need anymore questions, you know where to find me! Good luck! :)